# How to set up a client to an access point that's running DD-WRT?

Tags: dd-wrt, wireless-access-point

I've got a Asus W500-WL running as an access point with the SSID "HOMENET", G-only, channel 6, 20 MHz with SSID broadcasting.

It has also some security, WPA2 Personal TKIP+AES.

Now, I was hoping my older Linksys WRT45G running DD-WRT SP2 could hook up wirelessly so that I can use it as an access point for several wired devices that otherwise can't get in contact with the Asus (its placed at my homes entry point for the DSL).

I've set the Linksys in Client mode, SSID to HOMENET, G-only and set up the same security.

The Asus has IP `192.168.1.1` with sub `255.255.255.0` and the Linksys has `192.168.2.1` with the same subnet.

Could anyone point out some errors, it isn't working as it is? I've restarted both devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to change the Linksys IP-address to a address in the Asus IP-range. For example 192.168.1.2, and set the Asus IP-address as default gateway on the Linksys.
So the IP-settings on the Linksys should look like this:
IP-address: 192.168.1.2
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.1.1
Then, I don't know if it works anyway, but now at least you have the correct IP-settings :-)

Good Luck!